# Hang at Getting devices Ready

Tags: windows-8

I'm reinstalling Windows 8 as I do every year but this time however I'm getting extremely frustrated to the point I want to just throw every damn piece of technology out the window.  I've never had this much hassle installing any OS.

Last install of Win8 I had my Razer BlackWidow keyboard plugged in (both usb inputs in usb3 ports), my Logitech G600 mouse in a usb2 port, the printer cable in another usb2 port and the sound inputs from the blackwidow plugged in.  I had my SSDs in RAID0, with 3 other SATA hard drives plugged in.  Install went perfectly fine except that I would have to unplug all my usb devices to get it to boot then plug them back in when it did boot.  Never found a fix for it so I just kept doing that all the time.

Now however same exact thing to install, I get stuck at "Getting Devices Ready".  No percent sign for progress or nothing.  I've been Googling the past couple days to see what the hell is going on but all I find are posts about it from back in CP/RP release days and none of them have had problems I'm having.  It's either stuck before devices ready or at 20%, etc.

What the heck is going on I'm about ready to murder my rig I spent all this money and time on building.

Comment: You are going to have to eliminate which device is causing the installation to hang if you want our help.  I suspect its your RAID to be honest.

Comment: Well why would it be the RAID when I've had it installed on the exact same RAID array in the past?  I did get it past the getting devices ready and it went to getting devices ready 12%, then it crashed and said the error was DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION.  It rebooted and is now sitting at the loading circle.

Comment: Could it really be the firmware of the SSDs?  I've been using the same firmware the entire time (000f) for crucial m4s 60gbs in the past for the RTM version of Win8.  Is there a way to check what firmware version my SSDs have without having a OS installed?

Comment: Updated to latest firmware on both SSDs.  Disabled legacy usb boot in UEFI.  Trying to install again.

Comment: I am sure there is a way.  I suggest you research that on how to check the firmware of a SSD device.  I only gave you my thoughts on the subject of why your having a driver problem.

Comment: Got it working.  Turned out to be the disc was severely scratched -_-.  Only took 14 hours to figure that one out.